# Logic to manipulate dataframe in spark scala [Spark]

Tags: scala, dataframe, apache-spark, hdfs

Take for example the following dataFrame: 
x.show(false)

```
+-------+--------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------+-------------+
|colId|hdfsPath                                                                                                                                        |timestamp    |
+-------+--------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------+-------------+
|11    |hdfs://novus-nameservice/a/b/c/done/compiled-20200218050518-1-0-0-1582020318751.snappy|1662157400000|
|12    |hdfs://novus-nameservice/a/b/c/done/compiled-20200219060507-1-0-0-1582023907108.snappy|1662158000000|
+-------+--------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------+-------------+
```

Now I am trying to update the existing DF to create a new DF based based on the column `hdfsPath`

The new DF should look like the following:

```
+-------+--------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------+-------------+
|colId|hdfsPath                                                                                                                                        |timestamp    |
+-------+--------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------+-------------+
|11    |hdfs://novus-nameservice/a/b/c/target/20200218/11/compiled-20200218050518-1-0-0-1582020318751.snappy|1662157400000|
|12    |hdfs://novus-nameservice/a/b/c/target/20200219/12/compiled-20200219060507-1-0-0-1582023907108.snappy|1662158000000|
+-------+--------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------+-------------+
```

So the path **done** changes to **target** and then from the `compiled-20200218050518-1-0-0-1582020318751.snappy` portion I get the date `20200218` and then `colID` 11 and then finally the snappy file. What would be the easiest and most efficient way to achieve this?

It's not a hard requirement to create a newDF, I can update the existing DF with a new column.

To summarize: 
Current hdfsPath:

`hdfs://novus-nameservice/a/b/c/done/compiled-20200218050518-1-0-0-1582020318751.snappy`

Expected hdfsPath:

`hdfs://novus-nameservice/a/b/c/target/20200218/11/compiled-20200218050518-1-0-0-1582020318751.snappy`

Based on colID.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here is what you can do with `regex_replace` and `regex_extract`, Extract the values you want and replace with it

```
df.withColumn("hdfsPath", regexp_replace(
  $"hdfsPath",
  lit("/done"),
  concat(
    lit("/target/"),
    regexp_extract($"hdfsPath", "compiled-([0-9]{1,8})", 1),
    lit("/"),
    $"colId")
))
```

Output:

```
+-----+----------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------+-------------+
|colId|hdfsPath                                                                                            |timestamp    |
+-----+----------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------+-------------+
|11   |hdfs://novus-nameservice/a/b/c/target/20200218/11/compiled-20200218050518-1-0-0-1582020318751.snappy|1662157400000|
|12   |hdfs://novus-nameservice/a/b/c/target/20200219/12/compiled-20200219060507-1-0-0-1582023907108.snappy|1662158000000|
+-----+----------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------+-------------+
```

Hope this helps!

Comment: Well you didn't mentioned those condition in the question. You can edit the regex for replace as you want, here ` lit("/done"),` depending your requirement

Answer (score 2):

The simplest way i can imagine doing this is converting your dataframe to a dataset and apply a map operation and then back to dataframe,

```scala
//  Define a case class

case class MyType(colId:Int,path:String,timestamp:Int) // they need to match the column names

dataframe.as[MyType].map(x=> <<Your Transformation code>>).toDf()
```